How moving the center the of the Unit Circle affects the cosine function
Me and another Pre-Calculus teacher were discussing the following idea brought up by a student earlier today:
We gave an activity where the students would discover how changing the radius and the center of the Unit Circle would affect the equations $y=\sin\left(\theta\right)$ and $y=\cos\left(\theta\right)$. In one of the questions, the students were prompted to write new sine and cosine equations if the center of the Unit Circle moves up by $2$ units from $\left(0,0\right)$ to $\left(0,2\right)$. When designing the activity, the ideal answers were $y=\sin\left(\theta\right)+2$ and $y=\cos\left(\theta\right)+2$ because moving the center of the Unit Circle up by $2$ units means that we need to write "$+2$" at the end of each equation, since the midline of the graphs of both equations is $y=2$.
The aforementioned student had trouble understanding why we would write $y=\cos\left(\theta\right)+2$ if cosine represents the $x$-coordinates of the points on the Unit Circle. They mentioned that shifting the center of the Unit Circle up by $2$ units should have no effect on the $x$-coordinates since it is a vertical change that only affects the $y$-coordinates.
We looked at our course textbook, but it did not show any examples of how changing the center directly affects the cosine function.
When trying to visualize the student's concern, I started by plotting the Unit Circle onto a graph except its center was at $\left(0,2\right)$ instead of $\left(0,0\right)$.

(I had to plot the equation $x^2+\left(y-2\right)^2=1$ to produce this circle. I wonder if this equation has anything to do with the student's inquiry).
If I were to create a table of values for $y=\cos\left(\theta\right)+2$, I would immediately observe that when $\theta=0$, we get that $\cos\left(0\right)+2=1+2=3$. But at the $\theta=0$ position on the circle, we are at the point $\left(1,2\right)$. The $x$-coordinate when $\theta=0$ is $1$, not $3$.
I wonder if the following circle is a more accurate representation of $y=\cos\left(\theta\right)+2$. This circle, plotted using $\left(x-2\right)^2+y^2=1$, was shifted to the right by $2$ units instead of up $2$ units. Notice that at the $\theta=0$ position, the circle passes through the point $\left(3,0\right)$.

Overall, it appears that for $y=\cos\left(\theta\right)+2$, the center of the circle actually shifts to the right by $2$ units. This reminds me of the concept from transformations of functions where, for example, shifting $x^2$ to the right $2$ units yields $\left(x-2\right)^2$ because horizontal translations behave opposite of what we expect.
Based on this thought process, I now seek validation from the community. Was the student justified in saying that the circle cannot be shifted up $2$ units for the equation $y=\cos\left(\theta\right)+2$ to be true?

Shouldn't one of the equations use $x$ instead of $y$?

The circle is an entity comprising its center and circumference.
We are considering parametric equation which is a combined relation for the circle centered at the origin:
$$ x= \cos \theta \text { and } y= \sin \theta $$
To push up the circle up by 1 unit we consider parametric equation which is the combined relation for the same circle:
$$ x= \cos \theta \text { and } y= 1+\sin \theta $$
To push to right the same circle by 1 unit we consider parametric equation which is the combined relation for the same circle:
$$ x= 1+\cos \theta \text { and } y= \sin \theta $$
Considering equation $ y= 1+\sin \theta$ as a stand alone relation has no meaning for the entirety of the circle.
The same holds if the shift is 2 units or any other distance.
